# SharePoint List Filter - Apply Filters button

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, filter, list-webpart

In SharePoint Online, I have a web part page in which I have different SharePoint List Filters allowing to filter List Web Parts. I am facing issues regarding the Apply Filters button, especially with the "Remember my selections" check box.

1. It works for me as an admin but doesn't work for the users: they are unable to save their filters. I was wondering if it has something to do with permissions on the page?
2. I do have the following message:

[image]

After remembering my selections and going back to another value in the filter.

Does anyone know how to get rid of that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, check if the site collection is denied for adding and customizing pages via the following command:

```
Connect-SPOService
//after logining the SharePoint Online admin center
Get-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename | select DenyAddAndCustomizePages
```

If it doesn't return Disabled, try to use command below to allow adding and customizing pages, then check the result:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
```

For your second issue, i cannot reproduce. If you can select another option in the list filter dialog and start a filter?